# Shalom Zachor on Motza'ei Yom Kippur?

Tags: minhag, yom-kippur, baby-infant

[This](https://www.bhol.co.il/news/837760) Israeli news site quotes Rav Chaim Kanievsky saying to make a Shalom Zachor on Motza'ei Yom Kippur when Yom Kippur falls on Shabbos:

> הגרש"ב גנוט מרבני העיר אלעד מספר כי זה לאחרונה שאל את הגר"ח קנייבסקי
> מדוע שלא לערוך סעודה זו במוצ"ש או ביום אחר, שהרי סעודת שלום זכר הוזכרה
> בתוספות בבבא קמא ושם לא הוזכר כלל וכלל שסעודה זו נעשית דווקא בשבת.
>
> הגר"ח השיב ואמר שאכן הדברים נכונים, וכדאי לערוך שלום זכר ביום אחר.
> המתין ורגע והוסיף: ***שיעשו במוצאי יום כיפור***

Do any published seforim suggest this option for Shalom Zachor?

Comment: The Rama mentions Friday night. In Halachapedia they mention an option for Thursday night if YK is Shabbos. https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shalom_Zachar#cite_note-25